# BitVector library, changing value in splice of BitVector

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitvector

I have the following code:

```
from BitVector import BitVector
import struct
import ipaddress

def run_marker_function(marker):
        bv = BitVector(size=16)    # 16 0s
        m(bv, "27.246.2.177", "255.255.255.0")

def m(bv, R, R1):
    # converts ipaddr strings to binary
    bitForm = bin(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(R)))[2:]
    bitForm1 = bin(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(R1)))[2:]
    # R2 helper fn is the interleaved output of the 32 bit IP addresses in binary form (R2 is 64 bits)
    R2 = Interleaved(bitForm, bitForm1)
    # splits R2 into list of 8 items, each 8 bits
    frags = [R2[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(R2), 8)]
    o = 3
    f = frags[o]
    # bv[0:3] = 000 initially, I increment by o
    offset = bv[0:3].int_val() + o
    bv[0:3] = BitVector(intVal=offset, size=3)
    # bv[8:16] = 00000000 initially, I want to replace with the 8 bits of f - DOESN'T WORK
    frag = bv[8:16].int_val() + int(f,2)
    bv[8:16] = BitVector(intVal=frag, size=len(bv[8:16]))
```

and I get the following error:

```
 18         frag = bv[8:16].int_val() + int(f,2)
---> 19         bv[8:16] = BitVector(intVal=frag, size=len(bv[8:16]))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BitVector/BitVector.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
else:
   if size < len(bitlist):
       raise ValueError('''The value specified for size must be at least as large as for the smallest bit vector possible for intVal''')

ValueError: The value specified for size must be at least as large as for the smallest bit vector possible for intVal
```

But I don't understand why as I'm putting in the actual length of that splice of the bv. Also, I'm doing the same methodology in

```
offset = bv[0:3].int_val() + o
bv[0:3] = BitVector(intVal=offset, size=3)
```

which doesn't throw an error

EDIT
A similar instance of the same bug:

```
dist = bv[3:8].int_val() + 1
bv[3:8] = BitVector(intVal=dist, size=1)
```

Gives the error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/BitVector/BitVector.py in __setitem__(self, pos, item)
         if ( (pos.stop - pos.start) != len(item) ):
             raise ValueError('incompatible lengths for slice assignment 7')
         for i in range( pos.start, pos.stop ):
             self[i] = item[ i - pos.start ]

ValueError: incompatible lengths for slice assignment 7
```

Comment: The issue may be the value of `frag`, since it has to fit in the size, too. This is what the the error message is complaining about I think. Your example at the end with `offset` may work simply be its value is small enough to fit.

Comment: @martineau thanks that fixed it! I thought solving that would solve another instance of the same issue, but it doesn't (I added in the edit). dist is 1 so how come size=1 throws an error?

Comment: @martineau sorry just added

Comment: A size of 1 means the value `dist` can only be `0` or `1`. That looks doubtful...

Comment: @martineau hm I'm not quite sure what's going on anymore, sometimes when i run my code I get no errors but sometimes I get the wrong size errors :/

Comment: @martineau would it be possible to move to discussion somehow so I can elaborate further?